# pm2 on Google Compute Engine, multi-users development environment

Tags: google-compute-engine, pm2

So I did the following things:

1. Set up a git project and node application
2. Created a Google Compute Engine and installed pm2 globally
3. Used the gcloud CLI to log in at the instance
4. Pulled the project from Git and ran "npm install"
5. Used "pm2 start server.js --watch" to start the node process and watch for changes
6. Used "pm2 save" so processes will restart after reboot or other issues

The question that I have now is: What if my colleague wants to change anything on the instance... He can't login as me, he will log in on his username on the instance. So he won't see the pm2 log or pm2 running processes.

How do you set this up, where a team needs to have access to an instance. The easy way is to run the processes as "sudo su -". But my gut feelings say that shouldn't be the best solution.

Regards, Peter

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for this is to have `pm2` run as it's own user, managed by the operating systems service management (init, systemd, upstart etc). You can give both yourself and your colleague access by adding yourselves to the pm2 group, or by sudo'ing to pm2 user or (best) by deploying to the pm2 instance using CI/CD.

This has the advantage that it ensures that pm2 gets started up after a reboot, has its logs included in system logs etc.